# KEUbvKya proccess

Tags: macos, virtual-memory, processor

KEUbvKya process run in my macbook and using 99% cpu and 4gb memory .I Cannot End prccess
Plz see the picture [image: process screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Try running `kill -9 2746`.

Comment: What you’re describing ticks all the boxes for a possible instance of the Pirrit malware: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/weird-process-names-in-activity-monitor-maybe.2050971/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the Terminal app in the Utility folder.

Type `kill -9 2746`

that is sending the kill command (9) to the Process ID 2746 which is your (KEUbvKya process).

If it reincarnates (comes back to life) then we need more info to find out who is behind it. Please report on it.

Comment: I kill the process but run again with new pid

Comment: I was wondering, after all it is a OSX process (root),  (not yours) Not sure what it is but please Open Activity monitor select the process, then click on the little gear icon (in the menu bar) then select 'Sample process', report the first 20 lines in your post.

Comment: Analysis of sampling KEUbvKYA (pid 11674) every 1 millisecond
Process:         KEUbvKYA [11674]
Path:            /Library/KEUbvKYA/KEUbvKYA.app/Contents/MacOS/KEUbvKYA
Load Address:    0x107ff2000
Identifier:      KEUbvKYA
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2018-12-10 13:04:06.348 +0330
Launch Time:     2018-12-09 14:43:59.910 +0330
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.14.1 (18B75)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/sample

Physical footprint:         62.1G
Physical footprint (peak):  62.1G

Comment: Call graph:
    2577 Thread_1107379   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
      2574 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff6e3bc08d]
      + 1136 main  (in KEUbvKYA) + 417  [0x107ff4a41]
      + ! 1076 writeStringToURLOrPath  (in Foundation) + 216  [0x7fff4356ae5b]
      + ! : 1014 _NSWriteDataToFileWithExtendedAttributes  (in Foundation) + 224  [0x7fff4356b34f]
      + ! : | 640 _NSCreateTemporaryFile_Protected  (in Foundation) + 684  [0x7fff435a2934]